# Error while trying to run e2e rust ink! tests

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract

I'm getting the following error while trying to run `e2e` rust ink! smart contracts tests:
`#![feature(min_specialization)]` using the following command:

```
cargo test --features e2e-tests
```

I'm using [this example to run the e2e tests](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/manic-minter)

The smart contract itself compiles successfully with the following command:
`cargo contract build`

Here is how the e2e test looks like:

```
    #[cfg(all(test, feature = "e2e-tests"))]
    mod e2e_tests {
        use super::*;
        use crate::manicminter::ManicMinterRef;
        use ink::primitives::AccountId;
        use ink_e2e::build_message;
        use openbrush::contracts::ownable::ownable_external::Ownable;
        use openbrush::contracts::psp22::psp22_external::PSP22;
        use oxygen::oxygen::OxygenRef;

        type E2EResult<T> = std::result::Result<T, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;

        const AMOUNT: Balance = 100;
        const PRICE: Balance = 10;

        /// Helper to get Bob's account_id from `ink_e2e::bob()` PairSigner
        fn get_bob_account_id() -> AccountId {
            let bob = ink_e2e::bob::<ink_e2e::PolkadotConfig>();
            let bob_account_id_32 = bob.account_id();
            let bob_account_id = AccountId::try_from(bob_account_id_32.as_ref()).unwrap();

            bob_account_id
        }
```

Here is my Cargo.toml file:

```
[dependencies]
ink = { version = "4.0.0", default-features = false }
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2.3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
openbrush = { git = "https://github.com/727-Ventures/openbrush-contracts", tag="3.0.0", default-features= false, features = ["psp22"] }
my_psp22 = { path = "../my_psp22",version="1.0.0",default-features = false, features = ["ink-as-dependency"] }

[dev-dependencies]
ink_e2e = "4.0.1"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you see this macro `#![feature(min_specialization)]` in the error message it is most likely that you are not using rust nightly.
This macro is not supported by the stable rust version and you need to add `+nightly`to build it:

```
cargo +nightly contract build --release
```

You might be using [manic-minter](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/manic-minter) as example but you are using different ink versions than manic-minter which uses ink v4.1. If you use manic-minter example you do not need to worry about this `+nightly`because you will have [rust-toolchain.toml](https://github.com/swanky-dapps/manic-minter/blob/main/rust-toolchain.toml).

Also in your cargo.toml the version of ink and ink_e2e better be the same.

Please upgrade all of your contracts to ink v4.2.1 due to known security issue.

Comment: Im getting the following error when trying to switch to +nightly toolchain 

```ERROR: Mismatching versions of parity-scale-codec were found!
Please ensure that your contract and your ink! dependencies use a compatible version of this package.```

Comment: Try to use same set of dependencies like in manic-minter. You can move openbrush and my_psp34 under dev-dependencies

Comment: in general it is the fastest if you give link to the source code and let community try to see what is wrong. Otherwise there is a lot of back and forth and the answers can't be straight forward

Comment: your openbrush version is also wrong